# plotly graph_objects (go) selecting two lines from two dropdowns menu to compare in the same figure

Tags: python, charts, drop-down-menu, plotly, plotly-python

i am trying to compare two lines in the same fig in plotly go, the goal is to let the user to select two entities (i.e. countries) from two dropdown menu in the chart

[this is the chart with all entities active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jziA.png)

when i select different country in the two dropdown:
i.e. dropdown1 = Italy, dropdown2= France
the chart shows just one line (the last selected from the dropdown, so it update)but it doesn't plot the two lines in the same figure

[Plot with just one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBzhI.png)

this is the dataframe:
[dataframe head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxdt4.png)

this is the code i am working on:

```
fig1 = go.Figure()
for column in df.columns.to_list():
        fig1.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                x = df.index,
                y = df[column],
                name = column
            )
        )
        
button_all = dict(label = 'All',
                      method = 'restyle',
                      args = [{'visible': df.columns.isin(df.columns),
                               'title': 'All',
                               'showlegend':True}])
button_none = dict(label = 'None',
                      method = 'update',
                      args = [{'visible': df.columns.isin(df.columns),
                               'title': 'All',
                               'showlegend':True}])

def create_layout_button(column):
        return dict(label = column,
                    method = 'restyle',
                    args = [{'visible': df.columns.isin([column]),
                             'title': column,
                             'showlegend': True}])
    
def create_layout_buttonE(column):
        return dict(label = column,
                    method = 'update',
                    args = [{'visible': df.columns.isin([column]),
                             'title': column,
                             'showlegend': True}])
    
addAll = True
# Update plot sizing
fig1.update_layout(
    width=700,
    height=500,
    autosize=False,
    margin=dict(t=120, b=0, l=0, r=0),
)


# Add dropdowns
button_layer_1_height = 1.08
fig1.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            buttons=([button_all] * addAll) + list(df.columns.map(lambda column: create_layout_button(column))),
            direction="down",
            pad={"r": 10, "t": 0},
            showactive=True,
            x=0.1,
            xanchor="left",
            y=button_layer_1_height,
            yanchor="top"
        ),
        dict(
            buttons=([button_none] * addAll) + list(df.columns.map(lambda column: create_layout_buttonE(column))),
            direction="down",
            pad={"r": 10, "t": 0},
            showactive=True,
            x=0.37,
            xanchor="left",
            y=button_layer_1_height,
            yanchor="top"
        ),
    ]
)



fig1.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

- synthesized dataframe in same structure as you defined
- taken a different approach.  Rather than creating all traces and controlling visibility in **updatemenus**. Create two traces and control name and contents of y in **updatemenus**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# get some countries 
countries = (
    pd.read_csv(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/vaccinations/locations.csv"
    )
    .loc[lambda d: d["iso_code"].str.len() == 3, "location"]
    .sample(20)
    .sort_values()
    .values
)

# build data frame of same struct
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(200, 1500, [22, len(countries)]),
    columns=countries,
    index=range(2000, 2022),
)

# create a figure with two place holder traces
fig = go.Figure(
    [
        go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=np.full(len(df), np.nan), meta=i, name=i)
        for i in range(2)
    ]
)

# but data for y and name in when country is selected
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "x": b / 3,
            "y": 1.4,
            "active": None,
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": c,
                    "method": "restyle",
                    "args": [{"y": [df[c]], "name": c}, [b]],
                }
                for c in df.columns
            ],
        }
        for b in range(2)
    ]
)
```

[image]

Comment: That's beautiful @Rob, thanks so much for sharing.